# pygsheet operation time out [Errno 60]

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I followed all the instructions in 
https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But the script does not run well and reports a operation time out error.

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

I am in China therefore I am using a Proxy - Shadowsocks to access google server. The connection is quit well since I can watch youtube HD videos.

I am on Mac and python version is 3.6.

I have tried `gspread` and `pygsheets` both.  Below I only give `pygsheet` codes. I have checks credentials and api enabling as in https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html. Besides I tried to migrate from google api v3 to v4. The problem remains.

```
import pygsheets
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='client_secret_new.json')

wks = gc.open("test").sheet1

print(wks.get_all_records())
```

I expect the connection could be set well and all the data in google sheets could be retried, whether from `gspread` or `pygsheets`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import socket

import socks

socket.setdefaulttimeout(150)

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 1086)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```